# How to send an Android Push Message using Intels App-Framework?

Tags: android, push-notification, intel, appframework

I'm looking for a solution to send a Push Message from PHP in Intels App-Framework, but I can't find any good solution. I have found this:
https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017

But how can I get the DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID? It's very difficult to find some code or solution.

Comment: There is a link in comments: http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/ You can find info about registration ID there (with examples) :)

Comment: yeah but i dont have phonegap and i dont like to use a plugin. i need only the DEVICE_REGISTRATION_ID and then i can send push Messages from PHP :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found the Solution. I have forgott to type the IP 0.0.0.0/0 into the Google API Console. And i added the Google API Key and Projectnumber by the Push Category on Build Window.

Then i copy paste the code from http://docs.appmobi.com/index.php/push-messages/ into index_user_scripts.js (only number 2 and 3). Number 1 goes to index.html on the header section. Now it works fine, i can send messages from the Services Tab.